# Is it possible to hide the value of Textbox using Password Char?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a XAML Code which compose of a single textbox and I want the value to be hidden like in Winforms Password Char Properties. So my question is. Is it possible to hide the value of textbox using Password Char in WPF? Thanks

```
                       <TextBox x:Name="txtUsername" Text="{Binding Path = UserProp.Username}" FontSize="14" Margin="0 10" 
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Username" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True" 
                             BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderColor}" />
```

Comment: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-passwordbox-control/

Comment: @RobertHarvey you should have posted this as answer